# scraping video titles from playlists

Tags: python, web-scraping

I came up to write a scraper for collecting video titles from YouTube music playlists because sometimes videos are deleted. I am new to python. I wrote the code by an article:

I checked the functionality of the code on many websites (by changing the link, tag and class) and everything worked, but somehow it doesn't to YouTube.

how to get video titles from the playlist?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuDh46ey2oy-qmIqPH0o1ZUZ9BFuqvtBn'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
quotes = soup.find_all('a', class_='yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-playlist-video-renderer')

for quote in quotes:
    print(quote.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary reason that your code doesn't produce any results is because ***soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')*** doesn't contain your tags.

You can check this using  ***print(soup.prettify())***

I would recommend using [pytube](https://pypi.org/project/pytube/) to extract the playlist titles

```
import re
from pytube import YouTube
from pytube import Playlist


playlist = Playlist("https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuDh46ey2oy-qmIqPH0o1ZUZ9BFuqvtBn")
playlist._video_regex = re.compile(r"\"url\":\"(/watch\?v=[\w-]*)")
print('Number of videos in playlist: %s' % len(playlist.video_urls))
for url in playlist.video_urls:
    yt = YouTube(url)
    print(yt.title)
    #output
    Busta Rhymes - Touch It (TikTok Remix) Lyrics | touch it clean busta rhymes remix tik tok
    Shaggy - Boombastic (Official Music Video)
    Nobody - Mitski (slowed + reverb)
    Mitski - Nobody (Official Video)
    ...truncated
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you have read from stack overflow as you have referred same topics YouTube uses JavaScript so you can try out `selenium` package it gives ability to automate browser and you can extract data from it for more you can read from [docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

path="you're path of driver"
driver=webdriver.Chrome(path)

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuDh46ey2oy-qmIqPH0o1ZUZ9BFuqvtBn'
response = driver.get(url)    

main_a=driver.find_elements_by_id("video-title")
lst=[]

for a in main_a:
    lst.append(a.get_attribute("aria-label"))
print(lst)
```

Comment: thanks, but for some reason, it returns only the first hundred titles

Comment: @BhavyaParikh  The reason that you're only getting 100 items is because you need to scroll down to the end of the playlist.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is an enhancement of Bhavya Parikh answer, which used *selenium*. The code belows add the scrolling feature that I mentioned in my comment on Bhavya's answer.

There are several ways to scroll down a page and the answer shows one of these ways.  The code is also using headless mode, so the Chrome browser window doesn't show.

```
from time import sleep

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')

# window size as an argument is required in headless mode
chrome_options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')

# Hide the "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software" banner
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuDh46ey2oy-qmIqPH0o1ZUZ9BFuqvtBn'
response = driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(15)

# finds the body tag
elem = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")

# you can also use the html tag
# elem = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("html")

no_of_pagedowns = 100
while no_of_pagedowns:
    elem.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
    sleep(0.2)
    no_of_pagedowns -= 1

title_tags = driver.find_elements_by_id("video-title")
video_titles = []
for title_tag in title_tags:
    video_titles.append(title_tag.get_attribute("aria-label"))

# do something with the list of titles.

driver.close()
```

Comment: you're awesome!